# Error when creating Filterable Elements in Jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I hv done a program for filterable element using Jquery Mobile

When search for the particular character in the search box its displaying all the characters and names instead of the particular character I have searched

The output I got is this

[image: Output]

```
**Here is my coding**

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="header">
<h1> Names </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form class="ui-filterable">


<input id="myFilter" data-type="search"  placeholder="Please type here">
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-
autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
<li data-filtertext="hello"><a href="#">Abdul</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Alvin</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Balmer</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nixon</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Mitchelle</a></li>
<li><a href="#">william</a></li>
<li><a href="#">vincent</a></li>
<li><a href="#">domney</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Brad</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tarvin</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pamela</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Jenney</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Rose</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pepe</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ronaldo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Messi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kroos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Klose</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Neymar</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fabrigas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Iniesta</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cavani</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Silva</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Beckham</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: comment  here if you could not understand the question

Comment: When you type "D", you expect to see all the results starting with letter D, correct? So in this case, you would only want to see the lines "D" and "domney". Can you confirm this is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

You can see in the above image that when I type the letter "d" Im getting all the alphabets which I have listed in my coding...It would be great if you could spot out the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, jQM filters for items that contain the search text rather than items that start with the search text. For a starts with filter, you will need to use the filterable widget's **[filterCallback](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-filterCallback)** option:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageone", function(){        
    $("#myList").filterable('option', 'filterCallback', startsWithSearch);    
});

function startsWithSearch( idx, searchValue ) {
    if (searchValue && searchValue.length > 0){
        var theListItems = $("#myList li");
        var text = theListItems.eq(idx).text().toLowerCase();
        var filttext = theListItems.eq(idx).data("filtertext") || '';
        filttext = filttext.toLowerCase();

        //if either text or filtertext starts with searchvalue, return false
        if( text.lastIndexOf(searchValue, 0) === 0 || filttext.lastIndexOf(searchValue, 0) === 0){
            return false;
        } else { 
            return true; //filter this one out
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On pagecreate I am setting the filterCallback option to a javascript function called startsWithSearch. That function checs to see if a searchValue has been entered. If so, it gets the text and data-filtertext of the current listitem and checks if either start with the searchValue. Any items that don't start with the value are filtered out by returning true.

> **Here is a working** **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Kqz2j/1/)**

Comment: @Manikandan, you are welcome! This question inspired me to write a quick blog article about it: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/starts-with-instead-of-contains-filter-text/ Have a look as I slightly improved the code...